# Using vuetify3 v-data-table-server in my vue3 project

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

How can i use v-data-table-server in vue3? I wrote than v-data-table-server avalible only in vuetify2, and vuetify2 avalible only with vue2, but i dont wont to change vue version. I also wrote that i can use v-data-table-serve in Vuetify Labs with vue3, but i didnt find examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a pre-release version of VDataTable, you have to register the labs component as described in the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/#usage), i.e. add it to `components` in `createVuetify()`:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import { VDataTable } from 'vuetify/labs/VDataTable'

export default createVuetify({
  components: {
    VDataTable,
  },
})
```

Note that labs components are not production-ready. There are bugs, missing features, a lack of documentation, functionality will change, etc. You will have to deal with that.

Here is an example using `v-data-table-server` with Vue 3:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify()
const app = {
  setup(){
    const loading = ref(false)
    const serverItems = ref([])
    const loadItems = async (options) => {
        loading.value = true
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 300))
        const {itemsPerPage, page} = options
        const offset = (page-1) * itemsPerPage
        serverItems.value = Array.from({length:itemsPerPage}, (_,i) => ({
          id: offset + i, 
          name: `Item ${offset + i}`
        }))
        loading.value = false
      }
    return {
      itemsPerPage: ref(2),
      headers: [{key: 'id', title: 'ID'},{key: 'name', title: 'Name'}],
      totalItems: 42,
      serverItems,
      loading,
      loadItems
    }
  }

}
createApp(app).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify-labs.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-data-table-server
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    :headers="headers"
    :items-length="totalItems"
    :items="serverItems"
    :loading="loading"
    item-title="name"
    item-value="name"
    @update:options="loadItems"
  ></v-data-table-server>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.8/dist/vuetify-labs.js"></script>
```